# How to update inner HTML before and after a for loop runs

Tags: javascript, function, execution-time

I've built a page which, after submitting form, displays a chart showing the submitted data.

The chart can display up to 10 simulations x 10000 population size x 1000 generations, so after clicking the form the data can take some time to display.

I want to be able to update a div with an `id` of message with the inner text of 'Loading...' while the `for` loop doing the calculations is running, then remove the inner text after it has run.

If I `console.log("Before")` before the for loop, and `console.log("After")` after the for loop, the messages print out before and after the loop has run.

However, if I put `message.innerText = "Loading..."` before the loop, and `message.innerText = ""` after the loop, the "Loading..." message never appears in the HTML.

Here's a (very) highly simplified version of what I've been trying to achieve

I suspect the solution might be using `Promises` but I can't see a way of applying them to my code. Any suggestions?

```js
const form = document.querySelector("#form")
const message = document.querySelector("#message")

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault()

  console.log("before") // this prints BEFORE for loop ends
  message.innerText = "Loading..." // This is never displayed in html
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    console.log(i)
  }
  message.innerText = "Loaded" // This is displayed in html
  console.log("after") // this prints AFTER for loop ends
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="message"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the interface a chance

```js
const form = document.querySelector("#form")
const message = document.querySelector("#message")

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault()

  console.log("before") // this prints BEFORE for loop ends
  message.innerText = "Loading..."
  setTimeout(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) console.log(i);
    message.innerText = "Loaded" // This is displayed in html
    console.log("after") // this prints AFTER for loop ends    
  }, 10)

  
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: still it is not well clear how engine can interpret even without going to that line, I even tried with promise too https://jsbin.com/bupuzoxino/edit?html,console,output

Comment: It is just getting to the tight loop before it gets the chance to update the gui